# Why Can't I see the light in the Animation tab?

Tags: animation, lighting

I am trying to create my light source in the animation tab but it is not showing up no matter how high the light power is. What is going on and how do I fix it?[[image: the light is very high but it is not showing at all.]

I have look up everything I could.  (this is blender 3.4)
I was watching a video tutorial to create the sword and they managed to get light. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-XhO3OOPxQ&t=918s17:35

Comment: Are your Scene Lights enabled? https://i.imgur.com/LY71jYh.png

Comment: Yes they have been.